# What means 'ground truth'

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dont know what 'ground truth' means. My project use a 'ground truth to tf' node and gazebo publish some 'ground truth' topic that seems an Odometry message.

What does it means?

What is it intended for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187190/what-means-%27ground-truth%27/) by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-07-20

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In robotics, "Ground Truth" is the most accurate measurement available. New methods, algorithms and sensors are often quantified by comparing them to a ground truth measurement. Ground truth can come either directly from a simulator, or from a much more accurate (and expensive) sensor.

In gazebo, this is the exact position of your robot within the simulator.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) on 2014-07-20**:
Thanks for the reply ahendrix. What absolute origin of coordinates does groundtruth refers to in gazebo? And what should be in a real SLAM enviroment? The exact position known by the observer? Do you know what i mean?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-20**:
I'm not sure where gazebo puts the origin for the ground truth frame. You should be able to figure it out by visualizing it in rviz.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-20**:
On a real robot, ground truth can be provided indoors by a highly-accurate motion capture system such as a Vicon, or outdoors ground truth can be obtained through differential GPS.

**Comment by [Chipiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/19795/chipiron/) on 2014-07-20**:
Very thanks ahendrix, now its more clear! I did not find anything relevant on the web :(

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2014-07-21**:
I'll quibble with Austin's definition a little.  Ground truth is the actual information that you're trying to estimate with a sensor.  For odometry, it's the actual position of the robot, delivered by a simulation or estimated (with high accuracy) by high-accuracy sensors...

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2014-07-21**:
... Technically, no sensor can give you ground truth, since they're making measurements, but good ones (like the ones Austin mentions) can give you measurements that are close enough to ground truth that they can be treated as being such.

**Comment by [tsdk00](https://answers.ros.org/users/37919/tsdk00/) on 2018-10-30**:
@ahendrix did u try with motion capture/stereo for ground truth?